# SIGABRT Error - Porting app from xcode 3 to xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, sigabrt

I have recently ported over my iphone app from xcode 3 to xcode 4 and I get a SIGABRT error. I have located the problematic line (it's the commented out line -> in my app delegate implementation):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Set the view controller as the window's root view controller and display.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    //navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];  
    navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor   
                                                         colorWithRed:217.0/255   
                                                         green:33.0/255 
                                                         blue:0   
                                                         alpha:1];
    navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Any ideas why `navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];` is causing a problem?

EDIT: the compiler jumps back the main method and displays the sigabrt error.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); //jumps to this line
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have doesn't make much sense. Try this:

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

And remove the line `[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];`.